# selenium java. Unable to locate element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

Please can someone point me to the right direction with below code?

```
driver.findElement(By.id("div#h4clock a.location").equals("London"));
```

I used `getText("London")` but it did not work.

I am quite new so any advise would be very much appreciated.

I also want to have a string to store the element **London** and display it using `Println`.

Many thanks in advance,

Hamid

Comment: is that your actual id `div#h4clock a.location`? If you have iframes you have to focus on the iframe prior to `findElement(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector does not look like as an `id` that cssSelector. Try

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#h4clock a.location")).getText().equals("London");
```

**Edit:**

```
WebElement city = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#h4clock a.location")); 
String getcity = city.getText(); 
System.out.println(getcity);
```

Comment: I took slightly different approach but it seems like this one also failed.

Comment: WebElement city = driver.findElement(By.id("div#h4clock a.location"));
        String getcity = city.getText();

        System.out.println(getcity);

Comment: A basic but very important questions. How do know the selector wasn't an ID.

Comment: There are multiple things you can see. With `#` in css means `id` and `.` means class. And, there are some basic requirements of how an id should look like in the `html`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html). Basically, looking at the syntax I was sure it was not id

Comment: @Saifur: can you please explain your code? I have never encountered/used "equals" like this.. So, just curious what happens here.. Thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: @Subh Welcome back. Hope you have been good. Yes that code was little off. We discuss that in comments and resolved forgot to update my post. Thanks for pointing out.